# Fill svg path with arrow along with dot as head

Tags: javascript, html, svg, progress-bar

I am trying to create the svg path with a progress bar with a large dot. How can I achieve it with purely html5/css based solution?

[image]

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/fldeveloper/rLh2sr7u/

The relevant code is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="progress progress1" value="8" style="position: relative;"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="display: block; width: 100%;"><path d="M 50,50 m 0,-48.5 a 48.5,48.5 0 1 1 0,97 a 48.5,48.5 0 1 1 0,-97" stroke="#eee" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0"/><path d="M 50,50 m 0,-48.5 a 48.5,48.5 0 1 1 0,97 a 48.5,48.5 0 1 1 0,-97" stroke="#55b9e6" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 304.777, 304.777; stroke-dashoffset: 60.9554; stroke-linecap: round;"/></svg><div class="progressbar-text" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color: rgb(85, 185, 230);">8/10</div></div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. How are you going to update the progress bar if you don't use Javascript?

Perhaps you meant that it is a purely static progress bar that is generated on the server?  If that's the case, then why can't you just draw add a blue circle to the SVG wherever you need it to be?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau You are right that it can't be purely html5/css but will need javascript as well. I am actally using progressbarjs to draw some animated progress bar. The only problem I have is that I can't draw a dot on top of the circling line. Since its outside their scope of development, I assume it will have to be done with SVG graphic. I thought I can get some pointers about that on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herre is a CSS solution that rotates a circle into the right place, with a CSS `transition` for animation purposes. I have linked the dynamic parts to the radio button state, but that is not much more than proof-of-concept trickery.

Note that I have widened the svg `viewBox` a bit to fit the size of the circle marker.

```css
.progress {
    position: relative;
}

.progressbar-back {
     stroke: #eee;
     stroke-width: 1;
     fill: none;
}
.progressbar-line {
    stroke: #55b9e6;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: none;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    stroke-dasharray: 304.777px, 304.777px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 304.777px;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s ease;
}
.progressbar-marker {
    fill: #55b9e6;
    transform-origin: 50px 50px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 1s ease
}
.progressbar-text {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center; 
    top: 90px; 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(85, 185, 230);
}

input#r1:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-marker { transform: rotate(0deg) }
input#r2:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-marker { transform: rotate(90deg) }
input#r3:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-marker { transform: rotate(180deg) }
input#r4:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-marker { transform: rotate(270deg) }
input#r5:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-marker { transform: rotate(360deg) }

input#r1:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-line { stroke-dashoffset: 304.777px }
input#r2:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-line { stroke-dashoffset: 228.582px }
input#r3:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-line { stroke-dashoffset: 152.388px }
input#r4:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-line { stroke-dashoffset: 76.194px }
input#r5:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-line { stroke-dashoffset: 0px }

input#r1:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-text::before { content: "0" }
input#r2:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-text::before { content: "1" }
input#r3:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-text::before { content: "2" }
input#r4:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-text::before { content: "3" }
input#r5:checked ~ .progress .progressbar-text::before { content: "4" }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="progress" checked> 0/4
    <input id="r2" type="radio" name="progress"> 1/4
    <input id="r3" type="radio" name="progress"> 2/4
    <input id="r4" type="radio" name="progress"> 3/4
    <input id="r5" type="radio" name="progress"> 4/4
    <div class="progress progress1" value="8">
        <svg viewBox="-5 -5 110 110" width="200px">
            <circle class="progressbar-back" r="48.5" cx="50" cy ="50"/>
            <circle class="progressbar-line" r="48.5" cx="50" cy ="50" />
            <circle class="progressbar-marker" r="6" cx="50" cy="1.5" />
        </svg>
        <div class="progressbar-text">/4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In real live you would probably set the `style` attributes on the respective elements with javascript. The animation itself needs no scripting, just set the values.

```
var full = 4

function setProgress (value) {
    document.querySelector('.progress .progressbar-marker')
        .style.transform = 'rotate(' + (360 * value / full) + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector('.progress .progressbar-line')
        .style['stroke-dashoffset'] = 'rotate(' + (304.777 * (1 - value / full)) + 'px';
    document.querySelector('.progress .progressbar-text')
        .innerHTML = value + "/" + full;
}
```

Comment: It looks really nice and almost halfway through what i want. Could you show how can I animate this circular progress bar with dot at the end?

Comment: Done, with the assumption that what needs to be animated is changes of the target value in the browser